# Is there a difference between declare "use strict" on a global anonymous function or inside the controller? in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given this two options:

1

```
(function(){
 "use strict";
angular.module('someApp.controllers', [])

.controller("ctrl1", ['$scope', function($scope) {

         ....
 }])
 .controller("ctrl2", ['$scope', function($scope) {

         ....
 }])
  .controller("ctrl3", ['$scope', function($scope) {

         ....
 }]);
})();
```

2

```
(function(){

angular.module('someApp.controllers', [])

.controller("ctrl1", ['$scope', function($scope) {
        "use strict";
         ....
 }])
 .controller("ctrl2", ['$scope', function($scope) {
        "use strict";
         ....
 }])
 .controller("ctrl3", ['$scope', function($scope) {
        "use strict";
         ....
 }]);
})();
```

Is there some difference between those two? one of those is recommended or considered "better practice" within Angular? why?

Comment: Use number 1. Less typing that way. Other than that - they are equivalent. The only "benefit" of 2. is that you might decide to omit `"use strict"` for some functions. However, I'd personally argue that's a downside, as you _could_ omit it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some difference between those two?

Well, in the first one, the whole IIFE runs in strict mode not only each of the controllers.
This doesn't matter as long you are not using `this`, access only a few global variables and properties and call some functions, but in case you are making a mistake in the IIFE it might be helpful.

And of course it's less to write for greater benefit, so there's no reason not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The only benefit of the second snippet is that IIFE context is in loose mode, globals can be accessed as `this` in IIFE.

Not really a benefit for Angular, since it is client-side, so `window` can be used interchangeably with `this` in loose mode. Also, for IIFEs a

```
(function(window){
  ...
})(this);
```

construction is often used for the same thing (also minifies better, but may cause troubles if the script is wrapped with another IIFE in strict mode, e.g. when using Babel).